# How to find logPolar Magnitude scale parameter without manual experiments

Tags: opencv

I want to understand logPolar transformation. I have created a picture with a red circle [image: red circle] and then applied the openCV [logPolar transformation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html). 
Here is code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

r = 300
SOME_EXTRA_SPACE = 5
combinedImg = np.zeros((2 * r + SOME_EXTRA_SPACE, 2 * r + SOME_EXTRA_SPACE, 3), np.uint8)
cv2.circle(combinedImg,(r, r), r, (0,0,255), thickness = 3)
cv2.circle(combinedImg,(r, r), 3, (110,50,50), thickness = 10) # circle centr
polar = cv2.logPolar(combinedImg, (r , r), r, cv2.WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS )

cv2.imshow("origina image", combinedImg)
cv2.imshow("polar", polar)
cv2.waitKey();cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

So I am expecting the circle become a red line in the end. Instead i got just a transformed circle center:
[image: transformed circle center]

and if I change the M – Magnitude scale parameter of logPolar to 50 instead of radius - it is working as expected. [image] Why M is not equal to radius and how to find it without manual experiments? Isn't it enough to have a radius of the circle?